# Load, Compare & Diff Registry of Windows Servers & Clients on VHDs?

Tags: windows-registry, diff

We are deploying various Windows Servers {2008, 2012} & Clients {7,8.x, 10} and various custom applications, versions & special utilities.

Without bothering the audience here on specifics of each, we'd like to figure out what tools/ ways could we use to do a 'compare / diff' between the entire or partial registry of various online/ offline instances of these machines.

We can use Beyond Compare to file / folder diff compares between 2 instances, but not sure what can help load & diff/compare between registries of 2 VHD/ machine instances.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind Linux, I'd really recommend [winregfs](https://github.com/jbruchon/winregfs). It transforms the hive file contents into plain files and folders that can be accessed and handled by whatever your preferred diffing tool is.

Otherwise depending on your level programming expertise I guess you could hook into [one](https://www.libguestfs.org/hivex.3.html) of the many [libraries](https://github.com/libyal/libregf) for the [task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/offline-registry-library-portal), or just use a [NirSoft](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/08/19/nirsoft-releases-two-offline-registry-tools-for-windows/) GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this by exporting the hives using regedit, then using a text-based diff tool to compare the `.reg` files.  I happened to use `gvimdiff` and cygwin `diff`, but you could use any source-code comparison tool.

**Edit**: Regedt32 can open HKU or HKLM hives if you have the drive mounted.  Select File|Load Hive and choose the .dat to load.  See [full instructions on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732157.aspx) or [this tutorial](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-offline-registry-edit.html).

Comment: Hmm.. ok. I guess no tools for direct load & compare. Any way to load & export the HIVEs without booting into the machines i.e. offline and not online?